# Generating Rainbow Tables with Salt/Prefix

Tags: hash, brute-force, salt, rainbow-table

I would need a tool that would allow me to create rainbow table for custom password pattern. The pattern is 9-XXXXXXXXX where X is alphanumberic character and 9- is fixed prefix, as well as fixed number of X (9x).

I understand dictionary attack would be more logical step, but for my task I need to trade this storage for fast lookup speed.

Any newish tools/project that would allow me to do so? Even opensource project to edit would be great help.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here.